# Call to invoke Hudson rest api via HttpPost not working

Tags: java, rest, post, hudson

I want to invoke Hudson Rest api to copy job using `HttpPost` request. Following is the code which i wrote:

```
public void copy(String hudsonBaseURL, String originJobName, String newJobName) throws Exception {
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(hudsonBaseURL + "/createItem");

    List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", newJobName));
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mode", "copy"));
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("from", originJobName));

    post.setHeader("Content-type", "text/plain");
    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters));

    System.out.println(post.getEntity().getContent());
    try {
      HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);
      System.out.println("Response Code : " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());


    } finally {
      post.releaseConnection();
    }
  }
```

But above code returns 404 error code and says it not able to find parameters.

I used this link : http://blog.zenika.com/index.php?post/2009/02/22/Remote-access-API-et-Hudson for writing my code but only difference is , i am using `HttpPost` instead of `Post` which is an old api.

Any ideas here?

EDIT:

Blocked the line of content type and it started working, but dont knw why

```
post.setHeader("Content-type", "text/plain");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your server expecting a response which is not of type `text/plain`, for example - `application/json`. The `Content-type` header describes which sort of data the server expects to get. When you added this header you forced your request to be of type `text/plain` which the server can't handle. When you removed it, I guess (can't know for sure without seeing your logs) that the request was sent in the correct format.